# Can I layer Lemon curd and Lemon Mousse?

Tags: mousse

I have a friend who really wants me to make then a cheesecake that has a layer of lemon curd that is then covered in a layer of lemon mousse. I think this sounds great but will the lemon curd curdle my mousse?

Comment: What's in the mousse? Basically whipped cream based? And becoming a lemon mousse through what means? (zest, juice, extract)

Comment: why would the curd curdle the mousse? How will they mix? I thought you are layering them.

Comment: that is my thought, too. I wonder if the lemon mousse might curdle on its own, tho, depending how it is made.

Answer (score 4):

There are several recipies on the internet for this though most have the lemon curd on top of the cheesecake.  Mary Berry has a version where she includes the curd directly into the marscapone mixture, so it doesn't seem likely it will curdle.

Putting it onto the biscuit, then adding the cheesecake mixture might cause other problems, either the curd could be pushed out of the sides or moisten the base too much.

Comment: One way to control the moisture and firmness and content was an old trick of mine of creating a thick lemon curd custard, but this of course would adjust the original intent of creating a curd and cheese cheese cake.